# Use React Router (native) for React native?

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-navigation, react-router-native

I'm onto universal app, and wanna try React router for web and native.

The problem is that `react-router-native` doesn't have animations when routes change.

I'm thinking overriding `history.push` so that it actually starts a new `activity` (android) or `viewcontroller` (ios) and puts on top of current screen.

The new activity will pass `path` as a prop to RN and the new RN will render the proper screen based on the `path`

I'm not sure if this is sensible approach

- about react-navigation

I know there is a `react navigation` and it supports web as well.

I could choose `react navigation` if I'm starting out my project from scratch and create every page in web/app with `react navigation`.
I'm not sure if I could add react navigation to my existing web / app projects

Comment: The your question is, which one do you want to use, the router or the navigation??

Comment: react-router, because navigation would be hard to incorporate for an exsisting web/app I think

Comment: Why do you think it's difficult?